# Toggle Back and Forth Between Two Active Tabs On Click - jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Basically I have two tabs - I'd like to toggle back and forth between styles when one or the other gets clicked.

Initially, the left tab is 'active' and the right tab is 'inactive'. Active has a blue background, inactive has a grey background.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/s40ek76b/8/)

With my logic, I'm trying to say, if the tab is currently active when clicked on, do nothing.

Otherwise, turn the tab that's been clicked on into an `active` tab and the other tab into an `inactive` tab:

```js
function toggleActive () {
  $(document).on('click', '.tab-tab', function () { 
    //if the element that's clicked on has the class 'active',
    //prevent anything from happening
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    //otherwise, switch the active class to the tab that's clicked on, 
    //and make the other tab inactive 
    else {
      $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
      $(this).siblings('.tab-tab').toggleClass('inactive');
    }
});
}

toggleActive();
```

```css
.my-card-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
    table-layout: fixed!important;
}

.exam-or-tutorial-tabs {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.exams-tab {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.tutorial-tab {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.tab-tab {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    color: #000000;
}

.tab-tab.active {  
    background-color: #1481C3;
}

.tab-tab.inactive {
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-card-table">
  <div class="exam-or-tutorial-tabs">
    <div class="exams-tab tab-tab active">Exams</div>
    <div class="tutorial-tab tab-tab inactive">Tutorial</div>
  </div>
</table>
```

It's only (partially) working once, then fails. Can you please explain why that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Javascript code with the below code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab-tab.inactive', function () {
  $(this).siblings('.tab-tab').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
  $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass("active");
});
```